# ERROR_LINE() Issue with Azure SQL DataWarehouse

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

It seems like Error_line() function is not available on Azure SQL Datawarehouse even though other related functions like ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_PROCEDURE() are available? I am trying to understand why it's left out? and what are the alternatives?

Comment: there are dozens of these gottchas when porting from SQL server onto azure synapse SQL pool ...  Microsoft doc conveniently avoids detailing any of these however I am blasting through doing such a migration and will blog my findings

Answer (score 4):

The code you submit for execution against SQLDW is not the same as the code that is ultimately executed. This is a good thing! SQLDW uses internal representations for database objects so that renames etc are only simple metadata changes at the control node. However, this does mean that errors generated by the system do not line up, line for line with the code you executed. Therefore the ERROR_LINE() does not mean anything in this context.

You can see the code that is generated by looking at EXPLAIN or by using the DMVs (sys.dm_pdw_sql_requests).

JRJ

Comment: all languages have this challenge yet they manage to bubble back up and can supply the offending line where error happened ... golang is especially good at this ... certainly microsoft azure should be able to supply an alternative call to replace ERROR_LINE() for users of azure synapse analytics